# GraphQL Playground Keeps forcing server's context function to run?

Tags: graphql

It seems every time I log into GraphQL playground the context function is run continuously until the playground tab is closed.

What I'm trying to do:
If the user passes a token when making a request, then pass the user's information as a `me` object in the context.
I am able to get that to work, but I am worried that it won't be scalable as when I open up the playground, the context function seems to run every second or so, logging out the `User.findByPk()` line over and over:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "email", "password", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "users" AS "user" WHERE "user"."id" = 2;
```

Should I be worried about this when consumers eventually consume the API with Apollo Client?

Stack: `graphql-yoga`, `sequelize`, `postgres`

Here is a sample of my code:

```
...
export const getUser = async (authorization, User) => {
  const token = authorization.replace('Bearer ', '')
  try {
    const { id, email } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY)
    const user = await User.findByPk(id)
    if (!user) return null
    return { id, email }
  } catch (error) {
    return null
  }
}

const context = async ({ request, response }) => {
  const {
    headers: { authorization },
  } = request

  if (authorization) {
    return { models, me: await getUser(authorization, models.User) }
  }

  return { models }
}

const server = new GraphQLServer({ schema, context })
...
```

Comment: This is expected behavior. Adjust the polling interval or disable polling to prevent Playground from repeatedly sending the introspection query to your server.